# Can you help me to calculate time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
public static void complexityexample(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            count++;
        }
        k *= 2;
        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Can anyone write me the answer?

for example , I know that nuber of operations in the for loop is 2N+2,

and number of operations in count++; is N

but what for the other parts.

Comment: `for(int t=0;i<n;t++){` won't stop.

Comment: It was a mistake, there is for(int t=0;t<n;t++)

Comment: Being as you have an infinite loop, I think the question of time complexity is moot.

Comment: I have formatted your code, but you have a large number of missing brackets. Is this what you intended? In the future, please ensure that your code compiles and is legible.

Comment: @qcGold wants to add a comment: This site should help you with algorithm complexity, sure helped me while in school: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 9):

Time complexity is `O(2n)`. The bottle neck is :

```
for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
  count++;
}
```

Since `k` increases exponentially every iteration of `i`.

In the `i`'th iteration, `k = 2i-1`. This means iterating all values from `j` to `k` is `O(k) = O(2i)`.

Now, sum it all up for all iterations:

```
20 + 21 + 22 + ... + 2n-1 = 2n - 1
```

Where last equality comes from [sum of geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Note that the next inner loop:

```
for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
```

is not influencing the time complexity (in terms of asymptotic notation), since it adds `O(n)` time for each iteration of `i`, and this gets quickly suppressed by the exponential behavior of the first inner loop.

If you want to count the value of `count` at the end, it is the summation of the first inner loop, which as said is `(2n)-1`, and the second inner loop, which is `sum{n | for each i} = n2`.

Answer (score 0):

**(2^n)+(n*n)**

as them main loop is

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

2^n from :

```
for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        count++;
    }
```

and  n*n from:

```
for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st row ) 1 operation.

2st row ) 2 operations.

3rd row ) 1+n+1+n = 2N+2.

4 ) 2N+2

5)N

7) N

9)2N+2

10)N

13)1

Is this right.

And after all math calculations the final result is : 14N^2 + 22N + 11 - operations.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the complexity is exponential in the size of `n` due to the first inner loop - looping from 0 to `k`, and `k` increases exponentially for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

A precise methodology using Sigma notation would be:

[image]

Empirically verified:

When n = 10, number of overall iterations is 1123.

When n = 25, number of overall iterations is 33555056.

When n = 50, it took for ever to execute (I had to change variables type from int to long).

Indeed, this non polynomial algorithm is expensive.